# A mathematical object combining a vector and a set: an "indexed set" $Y\in \mathbb \cup_{i=1}^n \mathbb R^n$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, vectors

Consider a the field of real numbers.

A finite set $X$ of reals:

1. can have different cardinality;
2. elements are not ordered (or indexed).

A finite-dimensional vectors $v$

1. must all have the same number of entries (i.e. the dimension of vector is fixed);
2. all entries are naturally ordered (or not indexed).

My question is, is it common and usual to define an "indexed set" or "ordered set", and use it just like a vector of arbitrary dimensions? What are some resources that I can learn more about it?

Rigorously speaking, instead of having $X\in 2^\mathbb R$, I want to have $Y\in \mathbb \cup_{i=1}^n \mathbb R^n$.

Comment: I'm confused; how do you add un-ordered tuples?

Comment: @KentaS if a tuple is un-ordered then it is cannot be added. But if it is ordered then it can. Btw can tuples have different length?